# étale, smooth, and unramified for product of schemes

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry

The question comes from Liu's book. I already asked it on mathstack and I post here since I didn't get any answer at now (https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4873827/%c3%a9tale-smooth-and-unramified-for-product-of-schemes). Let $f_1 : X_1 \mapsto Y , f_2 : X_2 \mapsto Y$ be morphisms of locally Noetherian
schemes of ﬁnite type. Let us suppose that for every $y \in Y$ , there exists
i = 1 or 2 such that $f_i$ is unramiﬁed (resp. étale; resp. smooth) at all
points of $f_{i}^{−1} (y)$.
**I want to show that $X_1 \times_{Y} X_2 \mapsto Y$ is unramiﬁed (resp. étale;
resp. smooth).**

---

I will wright $p_{1}, p_{2}$ for the canonical projections.

**What I've tried for unramified,** is to consider an  $x \in X_{1} \times_{Y} X_{2}$. We can suppose $f_{1}$ is unramified on the first projection $x'$ of $x$. Let us wright $y := f_{1}(x')$. By Corollary $2.3.$ page $221$, we have $\Omega^{1}_{X_{1}/Y, x'} = 0$ SO that $\Omega^{1}_{X_{1} \times_{Y} X_{2}/X_{2}, x} = p_{1}^{*}(\Omega^{1}_{X_{1}/Y})_{x} = \Omega^{1}_{X_{1}/Y, x'} = 0$ so that $p_{2}$ is unramified in $x$. I can't get more unfortunately...

**Étale** is the same as unramified and flat. But I'm not able to show the flatness.

**For smooth** , I take $y \in Y$. We can suppose the points of $f^{-1}_{1}(y)$ are such that $f_{1}$ is smooth on it. This mean, $f_{1}$ is flat on those points and $k(y) \times_{Y} X_{1}$ is smooth as a $k(y)$ variety. So $k(y) \times_{Y} X_{1} \times_{Y} X_{2}$ is also smooth? I don't know if it works.

Comment: As stated this is not true. If $f_1 \colon X_1\to Y$ is the identity then $f_1$ is étale at every point so the hypothesis that there exists $i$ such that $f_i$ is étale is satisfied but $X_1 \times_Y X_2 =X_2 \to Y$ need not be smooth or unramified.

Comment: Hi, Indeed it's obviously wrong. Many thanks. Do you see a true statement?